Git merge does not bring all changes from a certain branch, but branch is up-to-date
I have two branches, main and NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40. Both are up-to-date.
$ git checkout main ; git fetch ; git pull
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
Already up to date.

On main, a specific file contains a specific string, what I can confirm with grep.
$ grep -r "qualifiedPersonelElectrotechnicianMechanic-marine" _reuse/de-DE/WHS_TargetGroups.dita
              <note id="qualifiedPersonelElectrotechnicianMechanic-marine" type="electrotechnician">

Now I am moving the the other branch.
$ git checkout NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40 ; git fetch ; git pull
Switched to branch 'NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40'.
Already up to date.

But this time, the grep command does not find the string in the same file, so we know that there is a difference.
$ grep -r "qualifiedPersonelElectrotechnicianMechanic-marine" _reuse/de-DE/WHS_TargetGroups.dita

Now I am trying to get the changes from main with
$ git merge main
Already up to date.

No change is found and no file is updated. But when I do:
$ git checkout main -- _reuse/de-DE/* ; git status
On branch NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   _reuse/de-DE/WHS_IntendedUseSupplements.dita
        modified:   _reuse/de-DE/WHS_TargetGroups.dita
        modified:   _reuse/de-DE/WHS_Warranty.dita

I get the changes from main. This means, I cannot trust git merge anymore to get all the changes from the main branch. How can I ensure that a git merge does what I expect it to do? And why doesn't it work as it should?

the fact that grep finds the string in main but not in NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40  tells that the files diverged at some point and these differences were not resolved by merging. most likely due to a lack of conflicts that git detected

Sounds like you asked Painter 1 to paint your house blue, which they did. The next day Painter 2 came and painted your house green. Then you asked Painter 1 to come by and show you their work before getting paid.

@TTT, indeed, it looks like a rainbow now.

This output
$ git merge main
Already up to date.

tells us that you have a linear history:
--o--o--X            <- main
         \
          A--B--C    <- NDS-PSG25-40,PSP25-40

That is, main is an ancester of the branch that is currently checked out. Under these circumstances, git merge main does not have to do anything, because there are not changes in main that are not already in the checked-out branch at C. It worked as it should.
When you later checked out the state of main with the command
$ git checkout main -- _reuse/de-DE/*

you actually reverted the changes that happened in A, B, and C (without commiting them, yet).
